central moments of random variable from _estimates_ of draws from the distribution function
I am trying to estimate the first two central moments of random variable $r$. The information I have about $r$ is a set of estimates $\hat{r}_i$ for $i \in \mathcal{I}$, each with corresponding estimation uncertainty $\hat{\sigma}_i$. Here is my attempt so far:
Let $w_i\equiv 1/\hat{\sigma}_i^2$ and $W\equiv \sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}}w_i$. Our first conditional central moment is a probability weighted average of estimates. We proxy for probability with inverse estimation uncertainty: $E[r| \hat{r}_i, i \in \mathcal{I}]=\frac{1}{W}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}} w_i \hat{r}_i$.
For the conditional variance we have $V(r|\hat{r}_i, i \in \mathcal{I})=E[(\hat{r}_i-E[r|\hat{r}_i,i\in\mathcal{I}])^2]=\frac{1}{W}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}}w_i(\hat{r}_i-E[r|\hat{r}_i,i\in\mathcal{I}])^2$.
Now for unconditional central moments. For unconditional variance we can use the law of total variance: $V(r)=E[V(r|\hat{r}_i,i\in\mathcal{I})] + V(E[r|\hat{r}_i,i\in\mathcal{I}])$. $$V(E[r|\hat{r}_i,i\in\mathcal{I}])=\frac{1}{W^2}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}}w_i^2\hat{\sigma}_i^2+\sum_{i\in\mathcal{I}}\sum_{j<i}\text{cov}(\hat{r}_i,\hat{r}_j)$$
which simplifies if the estimates $\hat{r}_i$ are independent.$$E[V(r|\hat{r}_i,i\in\mathcal{I})]=?$$ I'm stumped here. What is the probability weighted average?
Then for the unconditional expectation... $E[r]=?$ Not sure we can do any better than the conditional expectation with the information provided.
As a bonus question (for applying this to a real problem), if you had the estimates $\hat{r}_i$ as your only information about a distribution for variable of interest $r$, would you use the estimate of conditional or unconditional variance for your estimate of variance of $r$? Why?

Isn't this just an ANOVA calculation?

@whuber isn't ANOVA to compare means? I'm trying to ascertain the uncertainty in an unknown distribution where I don't actually observe draws from that distribution (I can only estimate the draws, so each 'draw' has some uncertainty)

"ANOVA" is an acronym for "Analysis of Variance."  It compares variances, not means.  (Comparison of means is done, when desired, with post hoc tests.)
